# Modified date not transfering properly in msg * batch

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a batch file which displays the date. The date has been modified to show only the numrical value (thats without the day name eg: ma, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su) this is done ussing the following code snipet.

```
%date:~3-10%
```

Works well only now I want it in a msg box however the following do not work

```
MSG * %date:~3-10%
```

i would like my message box to say (pendin the acctual date) 01-01-2012 not %date:~3-10%

dose anyone know a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substring syntax is wrong which is causing the erroneous display. It should be:

```
MSG * %date:~3,10%
```

You have a `-` where you want a `,`.

Note that your code is locale dependent. It will not work on all machines.

A more reliable method would be

```
for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz " %%A in ("%date%") do msg * %%A
```

I'm sure the DELIMS option could be simplified, but I don't know what characters are actually needed for all possible languages.

Comment: assuming a space between the DOW and the rest of the date, `for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("%date%") do msg * %%B` should work better

Comment: @SeanCheshire - That won't work on machines like mine where the DOW is not included in the value of `%DATE%`.